# Using Modernizr to detect if background-clip:text is supported

Tags: css, html, modernizr

So I am trying to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect if the css `background-clip: text` is supported.
I have researched and landed on that page:https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/199

So I added this on my website header:

```
   <script lang="javascript">
    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.testAllProps('backgroundClip', 'text') ,
        yep: '/css/desktop/menuBar.css',
        nope: '/css/desktop/menuBar-notextclip.css'
    });
</script>
```

In that case, both Chrome and Firefox get the "yep" result.

I tried this:

```
   <script lang="javascript">
    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.backgroundcliptext,
        yep: '/css/desktop/menuBar.css',
        nope: '/css/desktop/menuBar-notextclip.css'
    });
</script>
```

And both browsers get the "nope" result.

However, Chrome should get "yep" and Firefox should get "nope".

What did I do wrong?  It seems according to Modernizr github this test should work.

Thanks!

Comment: alert('webkitRequestAnimationFrame' in window);

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was not using the proper version of the js file, I should use the v3.  But on v3, it seems Modernizr.load is absent, I cannot find it.
I will raise another question about that.